# Angular ng-repeat over multiple table rows and ng-show

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here is a table:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="objs in Objects" ng-click="Click()">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="{{objs.img}}">{{objs.name}}</td>
        <td>{{objs.owner}}</td>
        <td>{{objs.timeSt}}</td>
        <td>{{objs.state}}</td>
        <td><progressbar animate="false" value="dynamic" type="success"><b>{{objs.metrics.Test}}%</b></progressbar></td>
        <td><progressbar animate="false" value="dynamic" type="success"><b>{{objs.metrics.Test}}%</b></progressbar></td>
        <td><progressbar animate="false" value="dynamic" type="success"><b>{{objs.metrics.Test}}%</b></progressbar></td>
        <td><progressbar animate="false" value="dynamic" type="success"><b>{{objs.metrics.Test}}%</b></progressbar></td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-show="param"><td colspan="8">lol</td></tr>
    </tbody>
```

I need to make a visible row by clicking and hide others that were visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you do not want to loop over the `tbody` element but on `tr` elements.

For repeating over multiple elements there are the `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` directives in AngularJS:

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="a in [1,2,3,4]">
    <td ng-click="param=!param">show second row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-end ng-if="param">
    <td>ja</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For your example that would result in

```
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat-start="objs in Objects" ng-click="param=!param">
    <td><img src="{{objs.img}}">{{objs.name}}</td>
    <td>{{objs.owner}}</td>
    <td>{{objs.timeSt}}</td>
    <td>{{objs.state}}</td>
    <td><progressbar animate="false" value="dynamic" type="success"><b>{{objs.metrics.Test}}%</b></progressbar></td>
    <td><progressbar animate="false" value="dynamic" type="success"><b>{{objs.metrics.Test}}%</b></progressbar></td>
    <td><progressbar animate="false" value="dynamic" type="success"><b>{{objs.metrics.Test}}%</b></progressbar></td>
    <td><progressbar animate="false" value="dynamic" type="success"><b>{{objs.metrics.Test}}%</b></progressbar></td>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="param"><td colspan="8">lol</td></tr>
</tbody>
```